# Is there a way to view historical flight loads for American Airlines or other airlines?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, flight-search-engines, american-airlines

I work for an airline and I'm able to view flight loads through a company travel portal.

What I'm looking for is historical data for American Airlines on a specific flights that flew last year. Even more public information like if the flight was sold out would be helpful.

Does anyone know of a database that keeps track of past flight information in anyway?

Comment: Isn't load data usually proprietary?  I'd be surprised if there was a public source.